# Using Resources in different WPF xaml user control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, resources

I have two projects. One is a library and other one is a WPF application. In my library project I created a resources file (Resources.resx) and added some string in it and made its access as public.

Now in my WPF project I added reference of library project. Now I am trying to use library resource file in my XAML control.

Here is my code. Here MyApplication is wpf project and MyLibrary is dll project.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApplication.LauncherView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:p="clr-namespace:MyLibrary"
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="{x:Static p:Resources.TextFromResource}" Command="{Binding LaunchCommand}" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

But at the end I receive these errors.

Error   1   The name "Resources" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:MyLibrary".
Error   2   Cannot find the type 'Resources'. Note that type names are case sensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For using the class, not in your assembly, you need to define assembly

```
xmlns:p="clr-namespace:MyNamespace;assembly=MyLibrary"
```

But for including resource, you don't need to include namespace, because it is not a class, and doesn't have namespace...you need to include resource file.. here is the right way

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MyLibrary;component/Subfolder/MyResourceFile.xaml"/>
```

After which you can use

```
Content="{x:StaticResource TextFromResourceKey}"
```

Comment: Ahh, in resource file, than just define assembly and put the right namespace of the Resource class like in my first sample, after which your code should work

Comment: It worked, well what's the logic behind it. Your worked (xmlns:p="clr-namespace:MyLibrary;assembly=MyLibrary") but mine (xmlns:p="clr-namespace:MyLibrary") didn't.

Comment: As I said, assembly definition is required when the class is not in the current assmbly... right, it could work without it, since you have referenced the correct assembly, but it doesn't, just implemented like that :)

Comment: The advice on correcting the xmlns directive is correct and helpful.  There is no need to pull it into a resource dictionary; in fact, the resource builder will create a strongly-typed resource class for access to the resources (so the note about "it is not a class" isn't really correct).

Answer (score -1):

You have use merge dictionary.

**< ResourceDictionary.MergedResources>
  < ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MyLibrary;component/component/Subfolder/MyResourceFile.xaml"/ >
< /ResourceDictionary.MergedResources>**

after that you can use it.

Comment: then define a assembly and put the right namespace of the resource class.

Comment: This isn't necessary.  Fixing the xmlns directive to add the assembly is sufficient to resolve the problem.